# Deducting Quantity of Inventory

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

I have two tables in my  MS Access Database database inventory and Orders

My tables:

```
Inventory
    ProductID,
    Product (Shirts, Pants),
    Amount 

Orders 
    OrderID,
    CustomerID,
    CustomerName,
    Date Order Was Made,
    Date Order is For,
    ProductID,
    Product,
    Amount,
```

I have my database connected to my program and saving the orders works perfect. I just want that when the order is saved in the database, the Amount from the Orders table is subtracted from the amount in Inventory

E.G If Bob order 10 shirts and 50 were in Inventory that 50 should turn to 40

BTW I'm very sorry if I'm not clear enough I'm very new to VB.Net so I may not understand everything said and thank you for the help

Comment: Since you know how to use vb.net code to connect to DB and save order, you need to up your knowledge by learning about the transaction. What you need to do is under same transaction, insert orders and update inventory.

Comment: could you explain a little better please ?

Comment: Here is perfect example https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2  ---> only in your case, first statement will be insert and second update. If the transaction fails, the entire set of statements will rollback and this is the key.